# Json.NET - Add JObject to JArray

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a very simple piece of code that I just cannot work out.

```
JObject obj = new JObject { "Name", "John" };
JArray array = new JArray();

array.Add(obj);
// throws "Can not add Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject"
```

I have tried many different things to add a `JObject` to a `JArray`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your problem is not the adding part.

Your problem is the initialization of your `JOject`.

Try this.

```
JObject obj = new JObject();
obj.Add("Name", "John");
Jarray array = new JArray();

array.Add(obj);
```

Comment: Thank you! As you typed it I discovered another method too I'll post as a second answer

Answer (score 5):

Another way to fix the problem cl0ud pointed out is to instantiate as such:

```
JObject obj = new JObject { 
  { "Name", pRecord.getName() } 
};
JArray array = new JArray();

array.Add(obj);
```

Note those extra curly braces